# How to apply __contains to formatted date with django ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to implement a database search and I need to filter queryset by date that contains search request. The problem is that users will see formatted date (like dd.mm.yyyy) and will expect search to see it the same way, but default `__contains` consider date in yyyy-mm-dd format. How can I apply filter to DateField before using `__contains`? I need a way using django orm because otherwise it will be too long (not using sql).

I tried to set `DATE_FORMAT = 'd.m.Y'` to satisfying format but it has no effect (even setting `USE_L10N = False`)

Also thought about creating custom lookup but not sure how to implement it

I need to apply `__contains` to all model fields, so I can't just reformat search value

Comment: you can convert the string to datetime object and use it do filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Annotate the date attribute to a `CharField` and execute your filter on Annotated attribute.

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, Value, CharField 
queryset.annotate(string_date=Func(
                                   F('YOUR_DATE_FIELD'),
                                   Value('YOUR OUTPUT FORMAT'),
                                   output_field=CharField(),
                                   function='to_char')
                  ).filter(string_date__contains=INPUT_DATE)
```

Comment: I need to format it with django orm to use it in ```queryset.filter()``` expression

Comment: `filter(date_attr__contains=datetime.datetime.strptime('01.01.2020', "%d.%m.%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))` works fine

Comment: I can't do it because search value can be smth like "01." and I still have to return instance with 01.01.2020 date

Comment: Sorry I've got you all wrong, I edited my answer and hope this could help.